# Having trouble testing my Employee TestCase

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble running unittest on my class Employee can some one help me?

this is the test_employee.py:

```
import unittest
from employee import Employ


class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):
""" Test for the class Employee"""

def setUP(self):
    """Create an employee and the amount of salary that is given."""
    first_name = 'Henry'
    last_name = 'Chou'
    annual_salary = 0
    self.employee1 = Employ(first_name, last_name, annual_salary)


def test_give_default_raise(self):
    self.employee1.giveRaise()
    self.assertEqual(self.annual_salary, 5000)



def test_give_custom_raise(self):
    self.employee1.giveRaise(8000)
    self.assertEqual(self.annual_salary, 8000)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

This is the employee class module:
class Employ:
""" Define the class Employee"""

```
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, annual_salary):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.annual_salary = annual_salary


def giveRaise(self, amount = 5000):
    self.annual_salary = self.annual_salary + amount
```

---

When i run the unnit test, it shows me that the class Employee dosen't have object attribute self.employee1.? why is that

Comment: self.employee1 is never initialized because def setUP(self) is never called.

Comment: Hi, did that help/solve the issue?

Comment: thank you very much! Andreas, sorry for the late comment!